# Как сделать такое же видео в фоне со сменой надписей

Tags: wordpress, видео, wordpress-плагины

Есть донор, но с видео я особо не работал, вставлять только его могу в записи.

Каким образом реализовано на [этом сайте](https://atom-media.ru/) видео в фоне? Одно есть, а как реализовать показ трёх видео и что бы был цикл и изменялись записи?

Код для отображение видео ниже + был установлен плагин Video.js - HTML5 Video Player for WordPress.

```
<section class="section section-nopadding section-videobackground">
<div class="video_background video" data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/background-768x270.jpg" data-video="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/maria1.mp4" data-placeholder="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/background-768x270.jpg"></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="mainpage__top">
<div><span class="mainpage__top__caption">Кухни Мария</span></div>
<div class="mainpage__top__lines">
<div><span class="mainpage__top__line mainpage__top--line-1">Увеличение трафика</span></div>
<div><span class="mainpage__top__line mainpage__top--line-2">на 32% к концу 2016 года </span></div>
</div>
<div><span class="mainpage__top__description mainpage__top__description--line-1">Широкая сеть кухонных студий: более 300 студий в 150 городах России и СНГ.</span></div>
<div><span class="mainpage__top__description mainpage__top__description--line-2">Более 30 кухонных студий в Москве.</span></div>
<div class="linkcolor"><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mainpage__top__button" href="#70" data-toggle="modal">Заказать звонок</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

сss

```
.section-videobackground{

    height: 576px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.video_background{

   background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/background-768x270.jpg);
    height: 576px;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.video_background video{
    max-height: 576px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: а где тут видео - слайдер? я вижу только видео в фоне.

Comment: У вас есть сайт на котором все реализовано, вот от туда и берите код.

Comment: @KAGG Design имел ввиду видео в фоне как сделать, так оно само по себе изменяется и подумал что это из рубрики слайдшоу

Answer (score 1):

Это не WordPress - сайт.

Блок "Наши клиенты" реализован на slick slider, который подключен как js-плагин.

Блок "Отзывы о нас" сделан, похоже, "вручную". html, css и простой js код на клики по кнопкам.

Видео в фоне реализовано js-плагином фонового видео. Плагин помещает видео и накладываемый контент в блоки с position: absolute. Все это обернуто в блок с position: relative. По окончании текущего видео запускает следующее из плейлиста (в нём 3 видео в элементах li).

Все это сделать несложно и самому при наличии некоторых навыков в html, css, js.

Для начала можно найти аналогичные плагины на WordPress. Их много, например [вот тут некий обзор](https://wpcafe.org/plugins/wordpress-video-background/).

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю, отпушу что смогло мне помочь

Comment: а как реализовать 3 видео  и 3 текста, смог сделать 1 видео и поверх что б там отображались надписи. Код обновил.